# Dialogflow and Skype Integrations - User Authentication by connecting to MySQL Database

Tags: python, authentication, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am pretty new to ChatBot using Google Dialogflow and i need to integrate the built one with Skype. There are many documents on the web i can refer.

Before a user uses this chatbot on Skype, I want to do the ***User Authentication by ChatBot by asking few questions*** like "Whats your name" and "Which department are you from" i.e, i want the Chatbot to intially connect to my company server DBs and check the user details to do the authentication.

Can you suggest me some good reference links (maybe with python implementation or Node.Js will be good) or any examples, please?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would do the following here:

1. Create a conversation in Dialogflow that will ask the necessary authentication questions like you mentioned and store it in context/parameters.
2. Call your webhook with the collected parameters. Details about webhooks are [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview).
3. Webhook will authenticate the user (or not). You can, for instance, use [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) package and authenticate a particular sessionId coming from Dialogflow.
4. Your webook can send an event to the user using the format [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.EventInput). For example:

```
{
  followupEventInput: {
    'name': "user-authenticated",
    'parameters': "",
    'languageCode': "en"
  }
}
```

This will programatically trigger an intent with a correct user response (either authenticated or not). Read more about events [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-custom).

5. For any subsequent Dialogflow requests, your backend/webhook will know whether the sessionId is authorized to access a certain resource, so you can act accordingly. The event mechanism can also be used in case you ened to retrieve more sensitive content from your DB.

I can also imagine a scenario where you use one Dialogflow agent for authentication only and then, after successful authentication, you link the user to another one.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Flaesh , thanks a lot. May i know if any other way without webhook?

Comment: Hi Dhinar, I'm afraid not. There isn't an inbuilt auth mechanism for backend servers. You will need to use the Webhook.